# Uncertain if an inherited project is asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I must develop on an existing project *(There is no documentation or any developers)*
that targets framework 4.5

There is tasks like this which return  return `Ok` or `BadRequest`

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(UserModel userModel)
{
    if (userModel == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    //......there is other codes
    return Ok("it is ok");
}
```

and in *startup.cs* there is some configuration

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var kernel = SetupNinject();

    ConfigureOAuth(app);

    SetupSignalR(kernel, app);

    ConfigureCors(app);

    SetupWebAPI(kernel, app);

    SetupStaticFiles(app);
}
```

I am asp.net mvc developer and not familiar with the above code. In my previous projects there is no `async Task` and *startup.cs* with app configuration.

I can open project with visual studio 2012 and rebuild or run succesful. There is no console.

Is this project asp.net core?

Comment: From the code shown that project is asp.net-web-api2 with OWIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the impression that you are trying to determine what framework the above code uses.

> Is this project asp.net core?

Short Answer: **NO**

Not so short answer:

`IHttpActionResult` is part of [Action Results in Asp .Net Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results) and is associated with results returned from `ApiController`

That `Configuration` method with `IAppBuilder` is part of [Microsoft OWIN Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt152002(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: thanks...There is performance problem with this project.Is web API 2 is good for performance?Should I move this to asp.net mvc because I am very well at the asp.net mvc...I search for asp.net core...They said core is very good at the performance but I don't know core

Comment: Each version is an improvement on the previous one. If you are not familiar with core I would advise reading up on the documentation as MS recommends that new projects start with core. Core merges MVC and web API into one stack. From my experience I have had no performance issues with Web API.